# "AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values" when trying to extract year from a date column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I got a dateframe which there is one column 'brth_dt' and its type is datetime64[ns].I want to extract the age of persons,however when input:
all_df['brth_dt'].dt.year or
all_df['age'] = (pd.datetime.today().year - all_df['brth_dt'].dt.year)

coming up an error:can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

brth_dt columns are like this:

```
    brth_date
1   14Oct1978
2   21Aug1970
3   06Jan1980
4   09Mar1992
```

any advice?thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You need to convert the column to datetime first using

```
df['brth_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['brth_date'], format = '%d%b%Y')
```

The you can use the dt accessor

```
df['brth_date'].dt.year
```

You get

```
1    1978
2    1970
3    1980
4    1992
```

Comment: thanks..hiwever,df.info() shows this column is datetime64[ns] and df['brth_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['brth_date'], format = '%d%b%Y') comes up with KeyError

Comment: That's surprising as the datetime values are usually in 1978-10-14 format. What is the exact keyerror message?

Comment: yes its type is datetime64[ns] and in 14Oct1978 format,that's what I am curious about...